# Is the following statement about value initialization correct?

Tags: c++, c++11

I do not understand the effects and requirements for value initialization as they seem convoluted. It states from the CppReference site the following:

> 1) if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

So if T is a class type (class, struct) and has:

1. No default constructor at all (`A::A(int)` therefore no default)
2. A user-provided default constructor (`A::A()` is the default)
3. The default constructor was deleted (`A::A() = delete;`)

Then the object is default initialized.

Does this not define every single scenario that a class could have effectively saying that a class is *always* default initialized (when using value initialization syntax, empty braces) *unless it has an implicit default constructor / defaulted one*?

In essence, is the following statement correct:

The only way for these criteria to fail is if the default constructor is implicit or C++11 defaulted in which case it is zero-initialized.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: No `=default`, no `=deleted` and no otherwise declared constructor, then you get value initialization. The End.

Comment: No, because if a user-defined constructor is provided, the default constructor is not synthesised. i.e. Rule #1

Comment: Upon further inspection - the requirements it set out seem to be almost defining aggregates. If it's an aggregate then they get zero initialized.